# Late fees for customer profiles with or without recurring billing subscriptions in authorize.net

Tags: api, authorize.net, fee

For a school that has many enrollments of children and their parents making payments, is there a way in the Authorize.net API to charge customer profiles late fees? They may be enrolled in recurring billing subscriptions or not. Does authorize.net allow late fees and balances to be paid? I'm wondering how to implement this with the APIs.

I find these APIs helpful, but not the complete solution: 
* Create a Subscription from Customer Profile
* Get Customer Profile
* Get Customer Payment Profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API call for handling with late fees. If your amounts to charge are going to vary for any reason, adding late fees being an example, you would want to build your own engine for making payments. The best way to do this is to use the CIM API to create and manage payment accounts and then charge against them. That way you can charge a varying amount if a late fee needs to be added. Of course this means you are responsible for handling all payments and cannot count on a built in scheduling engine like the one provided by the ARB API.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I will need to do some more research in this direction.